# How to find the repeat value in a mysql table with 30 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql

In Mysql, I have a table with two columns (id, uuid). Then I inserted 30 million values into it. (ps: the uuid can repeated)

Now, I want to find the repeat value in the table by using Mysql grammar, but the sql spent too much time.

I want to search all columns, but it takes much time, so I tried querying first million rows, the it spent 8 seconds.

Then I tried with 10 million rows, it spend 5mins,
then with 20 million rows, the server seem died.

```
select count(uuid) as cnt
from uuid_test
where id between 1
and 1000000
group by uuid having cnt > 1;
```

Anyone can help me to optimized the sql, thanks

Comment: Your table has 3000-watt columns?

Comment: Create in index on uuid column. It will take a long time to build but the select/group by queries will then become faster.

Comment: Seeing the asker is from China, I presume `W = 10000`

Comment: @YaobinThen I see: 10,000 = 万 = wàn = W. TIL! https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Big_numbers_in_Chinese#Ten_Thousand_-_.E4.B8.87_.28w.C3.A0n.29

Comment: @YaobinThen thanks, my english is very poor

Comment: It seems like you're dumping data into a new table, you could use @SalmanA's suggestion, but create the index before dumping the data into the table, it'll be faster than building index with existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query,

`SELECT uuid, count(*) cnt FROM uuid_test GROUP BY 1 HAVING cnt>1;`

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks,it works,it`s only needed 10s. It seems that the Where and Between conditions cause the query to be too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Often the fastest way to find duplicates uses a correlated subquery rather than aggregation:

```
select ut2.*
from uuid_test ut2
where exists (select 1
              from uuid_test ut2
              where ut2.uuid = ut.uuid and
                    ut2.id <> ut.id
             );
```

This can take advantage of an index on `uuid_test(uuid, id)`.